# Double trigger for jquery action

Tags: jquery, triggers, keydown

How can I get "count" to be incremented by one either if the button "next" is pressed, or if the right keyboard arrow is pressed?

I've tried like this:

```
$("#NextBtn").click(function()
$(document).keydown(function (e)

 {
  count = count + 1
  console.log(count);

});
```

But obviously I'm missing how to give this action a double trigger, don't know how to do it... Any ideas?
Thank you!!

Comment: It would work if you split it into two separate functions.

Comment: aren't you missing `var count = 0;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
var count = 0;

$("#NextBtn").click(increment);
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       increment();
    }
});

function increment(){
   count = count + 1;
   console.log(count);
}
```

Because everybody wants to know the keycodes:
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Added jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tFkpm/

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen, that's fantastic. Also, is there a way to code it so that the document doesn't have to be clicked first for the key press to work? At the moment i have to click on the page first, which is a big issue for the website :/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$("#NextBtn").click(increment);
$(document).keydown(increment);

function increment(){
  count = count + 1
  console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: you also need to check for if it is the right arrow.

 if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    count = count + 1;
  }

Comment: @StephenKing Hey Stephen, could you explain how to implement that? Thanks a lot!